# Ionic2 refresh current page

Tags: ionic2

I have a tabs page display user info ，there is a modal can edit user info ，after edit success，modal dismiss. How to refresh cuurent tabs page to show new user info ？

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @SurajRao There will be too many code. Think like a page showing user info，left corner has a button can open a modal allow you edit user info，if you edit success，how to make the page showing new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a callback function to the modal.

```
modal.onDidDismiss(data=>{
   if (data === 'success') {
//call load method of form
}
});
modal.present();
```

In the modal component you can call

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss('success');
```

or

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss('fail');
```

based on your modal result.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks，I think this very helpful ！